# DNS provider for unlimited subdomains with api access?

Tags: dns

I have a project in mind that will offer users their own domain, like tumblr does for example.

I want to find a provider that can provide:

- One top domain. eg: myproject.com
- Unlimited subdomains. eg: a.myproject.com, b.myproject.com, ...
- An API to create subdomains automatically
- At a reasonable price (if possible).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your DNS provider supports [wildcard records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record), then you just need a web host that supports arbitrary subdomains with name-based [virtual hosting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting).

This is a perfectly fine and scalable way to set up a family of subdomains.  For example, it's what StackExchange does: they just have a single wildcard DNS A record for `*.stackexchange.com`, which (currently) points to `64.34.119.12`.  The webserver running on that address then looks at the HTTP `Host` header to decide which site to serve.

Comment: That is a really good idea. This server that reads the header to decide redirection can new subdomains be added with out restarting it?

Comment: Certainly; for example, see http://superuser.com/questions/192686/can-i-reload-apache2-configuration-file-without-issues. Also, one way to implement this, if you're e.g. serving the content dynamically from a database, is to have the server map all domains to the same root directory and just have the scripts in that directory check the `Host` header.

Answer (score 1):

Creating individual A records for each account is one method. I worry about the propagation possibly being delayed.

In my zend application when users register they are asked to choose a user name, that name becomes their sub-domain name where they login. username.myapp.com The username is placed into a file `/etc/nginx/subdomains`

There is a perl script in the Nginx conf folder that reads the list of subdomains from the file and enters them as server names or aliases I forget which. Nginx is then reloaded with `nginx -s reload` this reloads the configuration files only, nginx (the web server) never goes down. So before the users even get to activating their email address and logging in their sub-domain is ready without having to use DNS records.

The application does validation when a user logs in at their domain it checks they are logging into their assigned sub-domain.

With this if people enter a sub-domain that doesn't exist they see a custom 404. Similar to if you go to http://asdfasdfasdfasdfa.zendesk.com/

If my application ends up with 100,000 users I rather not have to worry about 100,000 A records and simply work off a local database and file to manage the sub-domains.

Comment: If you don't use the wildcard DNS record, how is your DNS configured?

Comment: My mistake, I just logged into Amazon Route53 the application server which handles all the logins has a wildcard. But nginx and the application handles the sub-domains so that it's not allowing people to access just any sub-domain.